# INNER JOIN Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to display the information I have in these columns and it keeps telling me that the first_name column in my professors table is unknown. Does anyone know why?
Please help me, I've tried everything.
Thanks.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT courses.name, sections.section_name, professors.first_name, professors.last_name, classrooms.room
FROM courses
INNER JOIN course_section ON sections.id = course_section.section_id
INNER JOIN professor_course ON professors.id = professor_course.professor_id
WHERE courses.id = 1;
```

Comment: please post the structure of your tables

Comment: Here's the structure of my tables: courses, sections, professors, classrooms. Then the junction tables: course_section, professor_course, course_classroom, section_classroom

Thanks so much.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you haven't included **sections** in any **from** or **join**. You have the same thing going on with **professors**.

Personally, I prefer the readability of implied inner joins in this situation. A DBA may disagree, but as a programmer I find this easier to figure out what's going on.

```
SELECT courses.name, sections.section_name, professors.first_name, professors.last_name, classrooms.room 
FROM courses, course_section, sections, professors, professor_course, classrooms
WHERE sections.id = course_section.section_id
AND professors.id = professor_course.professor_id 
AND -- classrooms???
AND courses.id = 1;
```

Not knowing your DB structure, you can probably get what you are looking for with less table joins.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the original error anymore but I get this one: Unknown column 'course_classroom.classroom_id' in 'where clause'. Here's my query: 
SELECT courses.name, sections.section_number, professors.first_name, professors.last_name, classrooms.room 
FROM courses, course_section, sections, professors, professor_course, classrooms
WHERE sections.id = course_section.section_id
AND professors.id = professor_course.professor_id 
AND classrooms.id = course_classroom.classroom_id
AND courses.id = 1;

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot! Your query helped me sort my way out!

Answer (score 1):

You're not joining the `professors` table in your FROM clause, you only have `professor_course`.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the database, you probably misspelled the column in there.

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

u have completely wrong Query..

as u r selecting from different tables( `SELECT` clause) and there is no such table on `FROM` or `JOIN` clause

```
the tables you need : courses, sections, professors,classrooms
```

in

```
 INNER JOIN course_section cs ON sections.id = cs.section_id
```

u must include table `sections` before writing above condition

same thing for

```
    INNER JOIN professor_course pc ON professors.id = pc.professor_id
```

u must include table `professors` before writing above condition

i think your Query should be

**Note**: better to use **[alias](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/MySQL/Using_Table_Aliases.htm)**  for tables

#### ALL D BEST

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks a lot!